# Почему-то docker swarm не пропускает некоторые запросы?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Здравствуйте!

Запущен стек в docker swarm через команду:
`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml prod`

В стеке есть сервисы `nginx` (порты 80, 443) и `nodejs` (порт 3000).
При обращение как в `nginx`, так и в `nodejs` запросы отрабатывают через раз.
1-й запрос в `nginx`:

```
curl -L http://192.168.1.2/ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.105.2 port 80: Нет маршрута до узла
```

сразу же следующий запрос проходит успешно:

```
curl -L http://192.168.1.2/ping
{"time":"2018-04-06T11:51:02.869Z","status":"OK"}
```

и так идет по кругу.

Самое интересное если зайти внутрь запущенного контейнера (через `docker exec ...`) и проверить запрос оттуда, то все отрабатывается штатно и никаких ошибок нету.
А также если запускать `docker-compose.yml` через `docker-compose`, а не в режиме `swarm` то тоже все работает штатно и ошибок нету.

Укажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать. Или кто нибудь сталкивался с такой ситуацией?! 
Заранее большое спасибо!

Версия OS: `Ubuntu 16.04.4`
Версия `docker`:

```
Client:
 Version:   18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:10:01 2018
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:    Wed Mar 21 23:08:31 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Файл `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        depends_on:
            - my-app
        ports: 
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            #- /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
            - /home/project/data/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
            - /home/project/data/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /home/project/public:/var/public
        networks:
            - my-network
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 1
                delay: 5s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s

    my-app:
        image: staging.smartlab.uz:5005/smartlab/ucell/ucell-app
        env_file:
            - /home/project/project.env
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        volumes:
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
            - /home/project/public:/usr/src/app/public
        networks:
            - my-network
        command: bash -c "npm start"
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 1
                delay: 5s        

networks:
    my-network:
```

Comment: попробуйте указать `--advertise-addr=(interface | IP)`

Comment: при `swarm init` это параметр указан.